# platformio unable to find header file

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I have problem getting platformio to find header file for a certian library, I am using it pretty basic as the example for the library.

this is what I have in

platformio.ini

```
[env:esp_wemos]
platform = espressif8266
framework = arduino
board = d1_mini

lib_deps =
# Easy NeoPixels
  1590
```

---

and in main.cpp

```
#include <EasyNeopixels.h>

void setup() {
    setupEasyNeoPixels(13, 1);
}
```

and my error message
    X/source/test/src/main.cpp:1:27: fatal error: EasyNeopixels.h: No such file or directory

I have tried both with <> and '"', no difference.

my OS = Debian9
Latest platformio, not sure what version it is

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the "NeoPixelBus" lib as dependency:

```
#NeoPixelBus
  547
```

I am including the header in the same way, so I suspect it is a problem with the EasyNeopixels and PlatformIO configuration and my board/platform configuration